# How does the next code for passing a string from fragment_1 to fragment_2 works?

Tags: android, interface

i've been development a android project, i had the necesity of pass information from one fragment to another and i found this code, but i've been having problems understanding how it works.

The next code pass information from fragment_1 to fragment_2 using interfaces,

I not particularly understand the part when the object mCallbacks gets the Activity. (mCallbacks = (Callbacks)getActivity();)
And how the object mCallbacks that Fragment_1 has, calls the interface on MainActivity.

> Note: im going to put all the code, maybe it helps someone.

```
private Callbacks mCallbacks = null; 

public class frament_1 extends Fragment{   



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mCallbacks = (Callbacks)getActivity();//****************************
    }

   Public interface Callbacks{

    public void callMethodOnMainActivity(String folio);

  }

  Public void passInformationToFragment2(){
   mCallbacks.callMethodOnMainActivity("This String is passed using interfaces"); //****************************+
  }



}
```

This is the MainActivity that implements the interface that frament_1 has.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements fragment_1.Callbacks{

 @Override
    public void callMethodOnMainActivity(String folio) {//*********************
        //here you call the fragment_2 and pass the String has parameter.
        // no problem wthis part
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment module = fragment_2.newInstance(this, folio);
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.MainContent, module).commit();


    }



}
```

Fragment_2

```
public class Fragment_2 extends Fragment{

   public static Fragment_2 newInstance (Context c, String folio){
      //folio has the String passed
     Fragment_2 fragment = new Fragment_2();
     Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, folio);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        parent = c;

        return fragment;

}

}

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            //Here you get the parameter that ARG_PARAM1
            String folio = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        }

        mCallbacks = (Callbacks) this.getActivity();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step in understanding how a block of code works is to read it, and in order to read it you must adhere to the standards of the language; some of the things your code is missing is the following:

Indentation

Class names should not use underscores(_)

Class names are typically not in plural (Callback not Callbacks)

Class names must be capitalized (Fragment1 not fragment1)

Fields must be defined inside the class (mCallback)

Interfaces must not specify the member access qualifier (i.e. no private, public, protected declarations)

Let's see how your code will look now:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {   
    private MyCallback mCallback = null; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mCallback = (MyCallback) getActivity();
    }

    public interface MyCallback{
       void callMethodOnMainActivity(String folio);
    }

    public void passInformationToFragment2(){
       mCallback.callMethodOnMainActivity("This String is passed using interfaces");
    }

}


public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {   

    public static final String ARG_PARAM_FOLIO = "param_folio";

    public static Fragment2 newInstance(String folio) {
        Fragment2 fragment = new Fragment2();
        Bundle args = new Bundle()
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM_FOLIO, folio);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    } 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
             String folio = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM_FOLIO); 
        }
    }
}
```

Important notes:

There is no need to store the context in a parent field; you can always access the parent context by using the getActivity() method.

I'm removing the mCallback in Fragment2 because if you want to communicate back to the MainActivity you must specify its own interface in Fragment2 (i.e. each fragment will have its own interface to communicate back to the activity).

The best practice is to initialize the mCallback in the onAttach(Context context) method by casting the context to a callback type, and setting the callback to null on onDetach() in the following way:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super(context);
    try {
        mCallback = (MyCallback) context;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(this.getClassName() + " must implement MyCallback";
    }

}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super();
    mCallback = null; 
}
```

Now, let's take a look at the MainActivity code and see what's actually doing:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Fragment1.MyCallback {
    @Override
    public void callMethodOnMainActivity(String folio) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = Fragment2.newInstance(this, folio);
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.MainContent, fragment).commit();
    }
}
```

The callMethodOnMainActivity(String folio) is basically replacing the current fragment on screen (Fragment1) with a Fragment2 in which we pass a folio as parameter. So, nothing magic about that; but how is it triggered? Well, the Fragment2 has a field mCallback of type MyCallback that is initialized to be the MainActivity. So, when you call mCallback.callMethodOfMainActivity(String folio) on the Fragment1 you're, in a way, telling the program to execute the method callMethodOfMainActivity defined in the MainActivity.

It might be useful to get more familiar with the Observable/Observer pattern (you can google this or look at the book by the Gang of Four.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips............in the part that you say """""""""" how is it triggered? Well, the Fragment2 has a field mCallback of type MyCallback that is initialized to be the MainActivity. So, when you call mCallback.callMethodOfMainActivity(String folio) on the Fragment1 you're, in a way, telling the program to execute the method callMethodOfMainActivity defined in the MainActivity.""""
I can understand that im calling it, like if it were a method, but why can i do that? it is because im writting this (mCallback = (MyCallback) context;) so what exactly im doing with this part of code?

Comment: @Matvi you're casting the context object (which is the main activity) to be of type MyCallback so that you can call the method callMethodOfMainActivity. Without the cast you'd only have access to the methods in the context object